# Store a one-to-many vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, data-structures, one-to-many, key-value, keyvaluepair

This is perhaps a simple question, but I can't find the answer. How do I store key-value pairs where value is an array of numbers? For example:

```
 X = [1, [1,2,3]]
 Y = [4, [2,4,2]]
```

and so on. Which data structure should I use to store such one-to-many arrays?

EDIT:

I try to create a struct like this: struct(1, 1:3) but this gives an error "Field names must be strings." But I would need an integer here.

Comment: Are your keys unique? Is the number of values assigned to a key constant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [maps](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html):

```
>> m = containers.Map({1 4}, {[1,2,3], [2,4,2]})
m = 
  Map with properties:
        Count: 2
      KeyType: double
    ValueType: any

>> m(1)
ans =
     1     2     3

>> m(4)
ans =
     2     4     2

>> m.keys
ans = 
    [1]    [4]

>> celldisp(m.values)
ans{1} =
     1     2     3
ans{2} =
     2     4     2
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the structure on the fly. I don't have MATLAB here to verify this code, but it should work.

```
X.x = 1;
X.y = [1, 2, 3];

Y.x  = 4;
Y.y = [2,4,2];
```

Comment: Thanks, but doing that gives "Field names must be strings."

Comment: do you have variables called x, y? Try X.coor1, X.coor2 . . .

Comment: This comes upon creation of the struct. I do it this way: struct(1, 1:3) <--- that line produces the error. This one: struct('f', 1:4), however, works well.

Answer (score 0):

Struct is also an option.

```
>> x = struct('key', {1,4}, 'value', {[1,2,3], [2,4,2]})

x = 

1x2 struct array with fields:

    key
    value

>> x.key

ans =

     1


ans =

     4

>> x.value

ans =

     1     2     3


ans =

     2     4     2

>> x(1)

ans = 

      key: 1
    value: [1 2 3]

>> x(2)

ans = 

      key: 4
    value: [2 4 2]

>> x(1).key

ans =

     1

>> x(2).value

ans =

     2     4     2

>>
```